# Data not appending in the latest row

Tags: python, excel

Well I am copying data from a csv file and pasting in specific rows in an excel file. Here's the code:-

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
 
csv_file_path = r'C:/Users/krishss/Downloads/MMC.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)
latest_row = df.iloc[-1,:]  
 
excel_file_path = r'C:/Users/krishss/Downloads/good.xlsx'
workbook = load_workbook(excel_file_path)

worksheet = workbook['MMSC Statics chart']

if pd.notnull(latest_row['date']) and pd.notnull(latest_row['Column1']) and pd.notnull(latest_row['Column2']):
    date = pd.to_datetime(latest_row['date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    formatted_date = date.strftime('%d-%b-%y')

 
    row_values = [formatted_date, latest_row['Column1'], 28000, latest_row['Column2'], latest_row['Column3']]
    worksheet.append(row_values)
for row in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=worksheet.max_row, min_col=1, max_col=5):
    for cell in row:
        cell.alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
workbook.save(excel_file_path)
```

Now this code is working fine but instead of appending it next to the last row data it is appending the data randomly. Like a row is getting appended but randomly. I have tried many tweaks but can't get it to solve it. Anyone?

Tried many tweaks but didn't work. Data is still appending in a random row and not next to the last row with data.

Comment: Could you give an example of what is happening with the data? it only looks like there is one append happening each run of the script.

Comment: one append should happen after each run of script but instead of appending just after the previous data it's appending in a random cell

Answer (score 0):

I don't remeber exactly,I made lots of XLSX like this,
Can you try doing this, accordingly. and let me know please

```
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

for r in dataframe_to_rows(your_dataframe, index=True, header=False):
                ws.append(r)
```

Comment: where 'ws' is your 'worksheet'